# Which spells are hidden in adventures and other sources?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, published-adventures

When it comes to spells in D&D 5e, I had a very good overview. It's not like with subraces or feats, for example, which are scattered across a multitude of official and less official sources. The number of spells is quite manageable, as they are all contained in the *Player's Handbook*, the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*, the *Elemental Evil Player's Companion*, *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, and that one Unearthed Arcana article (*UA: Starter Spells*).

...Or so I thought.

Then I stumbled over *Flock of Familiars*, a 2nd-level conjuration spell that lets you summon three familiars at once. This spell appears in *Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*, an adventure officially published by WotC.

That made me wonder:
**Which spells are hidden in adventures and other sources?**

Comment: Are you just looking for a list of modules/books and all the unique spells in each?

Comment: I'm voting to close, as this is a list question, and the list will grow longer as 5e continues. There's no real way to know how many sources will need to be referenced here at this point, except that it's likely going to be a very long list by the time 6e comes out.

Comment: I voted to keep the question open, but it would surely be useful if the asker limited the question to a time period like, "up to December 2018".

Comment: I don't think the premise of the question is correct. These spells are not "hidden". Any campaign might has its own spells. Which spells are available depends on the game setting, the game genre and the DM.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl note that an answer being an ever-expanding list isn't necessarily cause for its demise; see [What are list questions? (RPGSE meta)](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6444/23970) for more discussion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Only 10 spells.

A careful [query on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=&filter-source=44&filter-source=21&filter-source=6&filter-source=26&filter-source=20&filter-source=7&filter-source=40&filter-source=8&filter-source=9&filter-source=10&filter-source=11&filter-source=34&filter-source=12&filter-source=14&filter-source=17&filter-source=18&filter-source=16&filter-source=25&filter-source=22&filter-source=35&filter-source=36&filter-source=37&filter-source=19) shows three spells from the [*Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/lost-laboratory-kwalish) adventure, for warlocks and wizards:

- [*Flock of familiars*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flock-of-familiars)
- [*Galder's speedy courier*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/galders-speedy-courier)
- [*Galder's tower*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/galders-tower)

And an additional 7 from Acquisitions Incorporated, a book that contains an adventure in it. As time progresses, you may need to update the filters in the query.

Comment: It might be worth referencing [this article](https://comicbook.com/gaming/2018/11/12/dungeons-and-dragons-lost-laboratory-of-kwalish-/) which gives some context about the new spells (and the *Galder's bubble pipe* magic item) included to honor Laurence Withey, a player who passed away of cancer but had worked with WotC earlier to have his character Galder immortalized in the adventure.

Answer (score 21):

### A comprehensive list

Here are all the 5e spells published by WoTC in sources other than the following:

- *Player's Handbook*
- *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*
- *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*

Not listed are:

- Spells that appear in one of the above three books, even if they were first printed in another book.
- Unearthed Arcana / playtest spells.
- Spells that are not published by Wizards of the Coast, even if they are available on D&D Beyond as "partnered content" (e.g. spells from *Tal'Dorei Campaign Setting Reborn* or *Lairs of Etharis*).

Note: The *Elemental Evil Player's Companion* contains 43 spells that were all reprinted in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, and the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* contains four cantrips that were all reprinted in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*.

### Acquisitions Incorporated

- *Distort value*
- *Jim's magic missile*
- *Gift of gab*
- *Jim's glowing coin*
- *Fast friends*
- *Incite greed*
- *Motivational speech*

### The Book of Many Things

- *Spray of cards*
- *Antagonize*
- *Spirit of death*

### Explorer's Guide to Wildemount

- *Sapping sting*
- *Gift of alacrity*
- *Magnify gravity*
- *Fortune's favor*
- *Immovable object*
- *Wristpocket*
- *Pulse wave*
- *Gravity sinkhole*
- *Temporal shunt*
- *Gravity fissure*
- *Tether essence*
- *Dark star*
- *Reality break*
- *Ravenous void*
- *Time ravage*

### Fizban's Treasury of Dragons

- *Nathair's mischief*
- *Rime's binding ice*
- *Ashardalon's stride*
- *Raulothim's psychic lance*
- *Summon draconic spirit*
- *Fizban's platinum shield*
- *Draconic transformation*

### Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica

- *Encode thoughts*

### Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden

- *Frost fingers*
- *Create magen*

### Lost Laboratory of Kwalish

- *Flock of familiars*
- *Galder's tower*
- *Galder's speedy courier*

### Planescape: Adventures in the Multiverse

- *Warp sense*
- *Gate seal*

### Spelljammer: Adventures in Space

- *Air bubble*
- *Create spelljamming helm*

### Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos

- *Silvery barbs*
- *Borrowed knowledge*
- *Kinetic jaunt*
- *Vortex warp*
- *Wither and bloom*