# What official books contain spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, books

I recently found the Encode Thoughts cantrip in the *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*, which has left me wondering if there are any other spells that I am missing.

**What official sources contain spells (as of 29/06/19) other than the Player's Handbook, Elemental Evil Player's Companion, Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, and Xanathar's Guide to Everything?**

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137791/28591

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To find out if a source has any spells, you can [go to D&D Beyond's spell search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells) and filter by sources. 
*This will work even if you don't have the books purchased on D&D Beyond*. The sources at the time of my most recent edit that have spells are:

- *Basic Rules*
- *Elemental Evil Player's Companion*
- *Player's Handbook*
- *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*
- *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*
- *Acquisitions Incorporated*
- *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*
- *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*
- *Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*

(for some reason the *Dungeon Master's Guide* and *Monster Manual* are listed as having all of the spells in the *Player's Handbook*, but I can confirm that they are not in there.)

- *Volo's Guide to Monsters*

(this book reprints *wall of water* as it appears as a racial spell for Tritons, but for some reason D&D Beyond does not show that fact )

Comment: Specifically, Acq Inc adds 7 new spells, the GGTR adds Encode Thoughts and reprints Chaos Bolt, LLOK adds 3 spells, and SCAG adds 4 cantrips. The PHB/SRD, EEPC, and XGTE add a more substantial chunk of spells. It's possible to see which spells each book contains by looking at the entry for the book on the marketplace (though I think it might only list a spell as an individual purchase option under a book if that's where it first appears): https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace